# stdClass object array inside of another array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, stdclass

I'm trying to get information from the $array1 below.

I'm getting with no problems venue's name and location address by doing:

```
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array();
foreach($array1 as $item){

                 $array2[] = $item->venue->name;
                 $array3[] = $item->venue->location->address;
}
```

But now I need to get the photos url and I don't know how to do it.

Thanks a million!

$array1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
               [venue] => stdClass Object

                (

                    [name] => a name
                    [location] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [address] => main street

                        )


                )

            [photos] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (

                                    [url] => http://folder/photo1.jpg

                    .
                    .
                    )))
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array1[0]->photos->items[0]->url
```

Remember - you access arrays with `[index]` parenthesis, objects with `->` arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Untested code:

```
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array();
$photos = array();
foreach($array1 as $item){
    $array2[] = $item->venue->name;
    $array3[] = $item->venue->location->address;

    $item_photo_urls = array();
    foreach($item->photos->items as $photo){
        $item_photo_urls[] = $photo->url;
    }

    $photos[] = $item_photo_urls;
}
```

Now you have a third array called photos , which contains all the photo urls.

Comment: You beat me to it + oned for the  loop that checks for multiple images and not using $array4 as variable name ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$url = $item->photos->items[0]->url;
```